# How to play a sound from JS in a UWP app?

Tags: javascript, audio, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a UWP that contains a WebApp that has some JS functions that invokes some C# functions. Nowadays, I'm trying to play a sound that I have stored in the Assets folder of my UWP app:

This is the function that I'm trying to play of my **Windows Runtime Component**:

```
public async void Beep()
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    async () =>
    {
        MediaElement mysong = new MediaElement();
        StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        StorageFolder soundsFolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("sounds");
        StorageFile file = await soundsFolder.GetFileAsync("beep.mp3");
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        mysong.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        mysong.Play();
    });
}
```

By the way, I also tried this code and it didn't work too:

```
public async void Beep()
{
    MediaElement mysong = new MediaElement();
    StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    StorageFolder soundsFolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("sounds");
    StorageFile file = await soundsFolder.GetFileAsync("beep.mp3");
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    mysong.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    mysong.Play();
}
```

This is the structure of the location of the file:

[image: location]

And this is how I'm calling it from **JS**:

```
CallJSCSharp.Beep();
```

I have more functions inside the Windows Runtime Component and all of them are working as expected with exception of this one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you intend to play the sound within the windows application or on a web page?

Comment: Within the Windows app, I just call it from JS.

Comment: Have you seen [this Microsoft Howto document?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-mediaelement-play-pause-stop-volume-and-speed)

Comment: And also [this document specific to UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement)

Comment: I just want to play the sound not have a visible control.

Comment: Perhaps this [Diederik Krols blog](https://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/Playing-sounds-in-a-Universal-Windows-MVVM-app) will be more appropriate then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix it:

1. I added both projects in the same solution:

   - UWP project.
   - Windows Runtime Component.

[image: example 1]

2. I removed extra code from the function (*it's unnecessary to add the Media Element in the XAML as suggested before*).

   ```
   public async void Beep()
   {
       MediaElement mysong = new MediaElement();
       StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
       StorageFolder soundsFolder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("sounds");
       StorageFile file = await soundsFolder.GetFileAsync("beep.mp3");
       var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
       mysong.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
       mysong.Play();
   }
   ```
3. Important to remember when you call any JS function, it must be with **lower cases** because JS conventions (even if your function has been written with upper cases).

   ```
   CallJSCSharp.beep();
   ```

More information about JS Conventions:

[Using the Windows Runtime in JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-the-windows-runtime-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`MediaElement` needs to be added to a XAML UI tree to work; you should just use the [`MediaPlayer` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer) instead. You don't even need to write C# code to do it - you should be able to access the API directly from JavaScript (if you want to). More on the [Media Playback overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback)

Comment: Hi Peter, as far as I know any JS that's invoking a C# function must be written in a Windows Runtime Control, I know that because it's not the first function that I'm calling I have functions for keeping the screen on, generating Excels from JSON or opening URLs in an external browser. That's why I'm sure there's a something wrong in my specific function. Now, let's suppose your scenario and I add the control to XAML, how can I choose it from the WRC? Because I cannot declare the class or anything else in the main project because of UWP restrictions. Thanks for your clarifications.