# Failure of decodeAudioData in Javascript Windows 10 UWP app for Microsoft store

Tags: javascript, uwp

Welcome any help with this puzzle. I'm trying to get this code working for a Windows 10 App for the Microsoft store using Visual Studio.

I am using [sound.js from Github](https://github.com/kittykatattack/sound.js/blob/master/README.md).

It is playing the sounds fine in Microsoft Edge, Chrome and Firefox (though it can't play any sound in Internet Explorer for some reason). In other respects the UWP behaves exactly like Edge in my tests.

The UWP fails with the error

```
message "EncodingError" String
name    "EncodingError" String
```

I tried both wav and mp3 samples and both fail with the same error.

The audio files have been added to the list of assets for the project, so that's not the problem.

Also the UWP is able to play sounds using AudioContext so it's not a problem with generating audio at all - it's able to make sine, triangle, sawtooth and square waves with attack. But can't load these samples for some reason.

This is the code I'm usiing and it is throwing this encoding error in the onFailed function.

```
//The `loadSound` function loads the sound file using XHR
function loadSound(o, source, loadHandler, failHandler) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //Use xhr to load the sound file.
  xhr.open("GET", source, true);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  //When the sound has finished loading, decode it using the
  //`decodeAudio` function (which you'll see ahead)
  xhr.addEventListener("load", decodeAudio.bind(this, o, xhr, loadHandler, failHandler)); 

  //Send the request to load the file.
  xhr.send();
}

//The `decodeAudio` function decodes the audio file for you and 
//launches the `loadHandler` when it's done
function decodeAudio(o, xhr, loadHandler, failHandler) {

  //Decode the sound and store a reference to the buffer.
  actx.decodeAudioData(
    xhr.response,
    function(buffer) {
      o.buffer = buffer;
      o.hasLoaded = true;

      //This next bit is optional, but important.
      //If you have a load manager in your game, call it here so that
      //the sound is registered as having loaded.
      if (loadHandler) {
        loadHandler();
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      if (failHandler) failHandler(o.source, error);
    }
  );
}
// ...

  //The callback function to run if an asset fails to load or decode
    onFailed: function (source, error) {
      if(do_throw_error)
      throw new Error("Audio could not be loaded: " + source);
  },
```

This is the [online metronome that I'm trying to turn into a Windows 19 Microsoft store app](https://bouncemetronome.com/visual_metronome/visual_metronome_with_drum_machine.htm) - if you use it in MIcrosoft Edge then the same code is triggered as for the Windows 10 store app and it works fine (I have issues getting the reverb to work in Edge but that's another matter and not a big problem for a metronome though it would be nice, that is a separate question anyway :) ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It is just that I hadn't added the files. I thought I had from Project >> Add Existing Item but that just copied them over into one of the other folders (the css folder or the js folder). I needed to expand to show the directory structure and then use include in project as for the solution here:
[How to play a sound from JS in a UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199184/how-to-play-a-sound-from-js-in-a-uwp-app)